# Creating modifiable GtkScale object in Glade

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, glade

I'm trying to develop a simple GTK application with [gtkme (1.3.5) library](https://github.com/doctormo/gtkme) and I'm having trouble using `GtkScale` object in [Glade (3.20.0-1)](https://glade.gnome.org/). I created one of them and it's defined in `.glade` file by default as:

```
<object class="GtkScale">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
    <property name="round_digits">1</property>
</object>
```

Yet the way it appears in Glade and my application makes it unusable, even after messing around with all of the available settings:

[image: Not working GTK Scales object]

I expected to see something like volume bars in pavucontrol instead:

[image: Pavucontrol scales object]

After messing around with the code from [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/glade-and-scale-widgets-424954/) I learned that changing object to `<widget class="GtkHScale" id="hscale1">` or adding `<property name="update_policy">GTK_UPDATE_CONTINUOUS</property>` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a completely working `Scale`, you need to define two elements: A `Gtk.Adjustment` (which does the math work and defines limits) and a `Gtk.Scale` which shows the element on the `Scale`. Without an `Adjustment`, the `Scale` shows as in your image.

So, in `Glade`, you need to define those two elements. The `Adjustment` will show as a non-visible element (see below), apart from the elements in the actual widget tree. The `Scale` will show initially as you've seen, and has to be connected to the `Adjustment` to actually show something. `Adjustment` and `Scale` are in different 'widget sections' in `Glade`, which might not be obvious:

[image]

and it will appear in the widget tree like this: [image]

In the `Scale`'s properties, you can select the `Adjustment` you want to assign to it. Of course you can do this also at run-time. The code to 'manually' make a working `Scale` is this (i.e. without `Glade`, but directly in your Python code):

```
    adj = Gtk.Adjustment(100.0, 0.0, 150.0, 2.0, 10.0, 10.0)
    scale = Gtk.Scale()
    scale.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
    scale.set_adjustment(adj)
```

You can define the `Adjustment` in `Glade` (or add it later) and the same goes for the `Scale` widget (though it's more logical to do that in `Glade` anyway.

Added references:

- An huge help while programming `Python` is Lazca's [`Python PGI API`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/) reference. It not only documents `Gtk` calls but a large number of other libraries which are similarly accessible. You can consult it online, or you can install a copy on your computer. Eg. [the parameters for the `Gtk.Adjustment` are here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Adjustment.html#Gtk.Adjustment.new).
- [One of the most complete tutorials for `Python` is here](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It just doesn't cover `GtkScale`, but is fairly thorough for the rest.
- There's [a huge number of tutorials on the 'net](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=python%20gtk%20tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=X9-MV9CyManX8geh8rTQBA#q=python%20tutorial%20pdf). Many of them are excellent. Rarely you encounter a more difficult problem, but even then you'll probably find a solution in someone's blog.
- And finally, another huge resource is [the `Nullege Python source code search engine`](http://nullege.com/). [BlackDuck's Code search](http://code.openhub.net/) used to be useful, though the interface was not entirely reliable. It seems it has been disabled now.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for Glade or GTK that says how properties like adjustment should be defined? All I can see is [examples in C](http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut-8.html#ss8.2), nothing about XML. Could you please add a  description on what are these magical values in Gtk.Adjustment constructor?

Comment: If you mean Glade's XML, then I can tell it is probably *never* necessary to edit that manually (you should avoid that at all costs). Both the Adjustment and the Scale are available directly from Glade's GUI. I've added some references which I frequently use, to the answer above.